# Generate a colour based on a name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, colors

I would like to pick a colour from a predefined list of colours based on a persons name using Javascript.

I want to have a coloured circle with the first letter of the persons name in the middle. The desired effect is much like what Google do with users who do not have pictures associated with their account in apps like inbox or contacts.

I want the colour that gets returned for the name to always be the same colour for the name, so using random numbers is out of the question.

I do not want to generate a hex colour between #000000 and #FFFFFF as I want to be in control of the palette, and want to limit the number of colours, so the answers to this question are not sufficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well.. there are more than one possibilities you can try. You can allow choosing from a list of finite predefined colors and set the chosen one with the username (save it in some db).

Comment: Hm... is relation 1) one specific name = one color OR 2) one letter from name = part of color definition? (if you know what i mean?) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a hash table?

Just create some algorithm for hashing the name of a person and mod it by the length of the colours you want. For example:

```
var colours = ['#345321', '#888888', '#000011'];
function generateColour( name ){
    // this is NOT a great hash but serves as an example
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        sum += name.charAt(i);
    }
    return sum % colours.length;
}

console.log( colours[generateColour( "Steve" )] );
```

A quick Google on string hashing algorithms will yield you far better algorithms.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, but with charCodeAt. Thanks

Comment: Use of modulo is genius! I found this example to be quite elegant: https://codepen.io/sergiopedercini/pen/RLJYLj (calculates a HSL colour from string)

Answer (score 0):

Put the colors you allow in an array and use the last digit(s) of the name hash to select the color from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hash the string into a number and to shrink that number into a valid hue A hue is an angle in the color palette, from 0 to 360, so you can just do `hash % 360` to get a valid hue. Then, you can make a color with the hsl() CSS3 function `hsl(hue, 100%, 50%)`. By making the saturation and lightness fixed, you'll get better results. This is a CSS function, so you have to write it in a JavaScript string and set that string as the CSS color.